# Godot: "Can't add child, already has parent"

Tags: godot

I am trying to spawn a bunch of trees in a 3d space randomly.
Code:

```
extends Spatial

var position = Vector3.ZERO

onready var tree = preload("res://TREE.tscn")

var tree_amount = 400
var tree_count = 0
var can_add_tree = true

func _ready():
    randomize()

func _process(delta):
    position.x = rand_range(-200, 200)
    position.z = rand_range(-200, 200)
    
    var new_tree = tree.instance()
    
    if can_add_tree:
        for i in range(tree_amount):
            add_child(new_tree)
            new_tree.set_global_translation(position)
            
            tree_count += 1
            
            if tree_count == tree_amount:
                can_add_tree = false
```

However, when I run this it gives me the message "Can't add child TREE to Main3D, already has parent Main3D". How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

With this line you create a new tree:

```
var new_tree = tree.instance()
```

With this line you add it to the scene:

```
add_child(new_tree)
```

The issue is that you are creating a single new tree and adding it to the scene multiple times in a loop.

Instead, create a new tree inside the loop. So each iteration of the loop is a new tree.

---

**Addendum**: Did you mean to add a new tree each frame (each time `_process` runs)? In that case, don't do a loop at all. On the flip side, if you want to create the trees at the start, you probably can run the code in `_ready`.